# How to get the list of nodes edited by an specific user?

Tags: 8, nodes

I need to be able to see all the nodes that have been edited by an user and be able to download that info, I've been searching for a module but I can't find one.

On the log messages report I can see that info but I can't download it and also it only shows the data for the last month.

Comment: This is for Drupal 8?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Drupal 8!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Views to export that data for you, here are the rough steps,

1. Create a Page view which shows content.
2. Select the fields you want to see for the node like nid, title, author, etc.
3. Add Author as a filter and expose this field so that you can provide user id or username via the exposed filter form.
4. Save the view.
5. The page view should now work on the URL you provided in step 1. Here once you provide a username or user id (depending on which field you exposed) the content should get filtered.
6. Add a module like views_data_export, which allows you to export the list in a file.

These are very rough steps but you can play around with it to get it working, let me know if you need exact steps.

Comment: The node author is not always the revision author, I think that you are missing something in your solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, it's working perfectly. Is it possible tot find the field for the user who made the last revision?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ll get all nid of revision of an user :

> All node revision are store in the node_revision table.

```
  $connection = \Drupal::database();
  $query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT(nid) FROM node_revision where revision_uid = 1");
  $result = $query->fetchAll();
  //devel module
  kint($result);
```

node_revision aren't entity so the only way you have is to do a manuel query.

> And if you need to filter by content type :

```
      $connection = \Drupal::database();
      $query = $connection->query("
      SELECT DISTINCT(node_revision.nid) 
      FROM node_revision
      LEFT JOIN node ON node_revision.nid = node.nid
      WHERE node_revision.revision_uid = 1 and node.type='page'"

);
      $result = $query->fetchAll();
      //devel module
      kint($result);
```

In this table you can get the revision_log field too.

Then you can use entityManager for load all your node :

```
 \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
```

you need to build your $nids array with the query result.

You can load all revision too by node id.

Answer (score -1):

For Drupal 8 with the following code you can get the nids that have been edited by the user:

```
// List of modified nodes.
$modified_nodes = [];
// The user id.
$uid = 5;
//Load all the nodes.
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple();
foreach($nodes as $node) {
// Getting the revisions for each node.
$vids = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->revisionIds($node);
foreach ($vids as $vid) {
  // Loading revision.
  if ($revision = node_revision_load($vid)) {
    // Checking the uid and the owner.
    if($revision->getRevisionAuthor()->id() == $uid) {
      $modified_nodes[] = $node->id();
      break;
       }
    }
  }
}
// To use dpm you need the devel module.
dpm($modified_nodes);
```

Comment: @Patty if my answer helps you consider to check it as accepted to help other users to find the correct way, if you don't know how to do it take the tour https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: for me this code is not good. it work but you loop on all node ?! i ll try to answer tomorow, but with entityQuery first you ll get nid with a query condition.

Comment: It will be great if it can loop through all the nodes of a certain content type

Comment: its possible with entityQuery, i ll post an example tomorow, its night for me right now.